# How to trim all characters and numbers from INPUT?

Tags: javascript

so i have this function that displays the inputted value of the user. I want to erase them all after clicking a specific button.

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<center> Are you sure you want to delete all?<br><br></center>
        <div id="options11" onclick="EraseMe()"> Yes</div> 
        <div id="options12" onclick="CloseButton()">No</div>
```

JS:

```
function List(){
    document.getElementById('order').innerHTML += document.getElementById('Name').value + document.getElementById('quan').value + parseInt(document.getElementById('Total').value);} //gets the inputted value of the user

function EraseMe(){
var name = document.getElementById('Name').value;
var quan = document.getElementById('quan').value;
var totals = document.getElementById('Total').value;

name.replace(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/, "");
    quan.replace(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/, "");
    totals.replace(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/, "");}
```

and also, i want to sum up all the value of the document.getElementById('Total') , but the result I'm having is a value of a string, not as an integer.

Here's the code for that:

```
function compute(){
    totall = document.getElementById('quan') * document.getElementById('price');
document.getElementById('totalsss').value += parseInt(totall);
document.getElementById('totalsss').innerHTML = document.getElementById('totalsss').value;}
```

Comment: Ask one question at a time.

Comment: Please look at many of the EXISTING questions on this topic before asking a new one.

Comment: BTW: document.getElementById('quan') gives you a reference to the DOM ELEMENT, not the value in that element. You need: document.getElementById('quan').value

Answer (score 0):

One problem, is that replace is a *pure function* and *does not* modify the input - as such, the *result* of `String.replace` must be used.

Another is the regular expression is anchored (meaning it would only match input of a single character in the given case), and yet another is the regular expression is not global (meaning  it would only match once) ..

Try:

```
var nameElm = document.getElementById('Name');
// assign replacement result back to input's value,
// after substituting all (g) English alphabet characters/numbers
// with nothing .. any other characters will remain
nameElm.value = nameElm.value.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "");
```

Comment: oh, how can I call the function?

Comment: this:
    var nameElm = document.getElementById('Name');
// assign replacement result back to input's value,
// after substituting all (g) English alphabet characters/numbers
// with nothing .. any other characters will remain
nameElm.value = nameElm.value.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "");

i want the values to be deleted after the user clicked a specific button.

Comment: So put the code in your "Delete Button Clicked" function.

Comment: it won't work :(
    function EraseMe(){
 document.getElementById('Name').value;
 document.getElementById('quan').value;
 document.getElementById('Totality').value;

 var nameElm = document.getElementById('Name');
 nameElm.value = nameElm.value.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "");
 
 document.getElementById('Name').innerHTML = nameElm.value;}

Comment: @user3359381 "it won't work" is a very poor way to report a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to blank something, just replace it with an empty string:

```
function EraseMe(){
    document.getElementById('Name').value = "";
    document.getElementById('quan').value = "";
    document.getElementById('Total').value = "";
}
```

There's no reason to do that regex replacement unless there's something you want to keep.

Comment: @user3359381: Then you are going something wrong, because it absolutely does work. See: http://jsfiddle.net/d6S5g/

Comment: @user3359381: Check your ids actually correspond to elements with the same id (note: they are case sensitive and your casing seems to be all over the place).